# multiline find and replace using regex and UltraEdit

Tags: regex

I need to do a smart parse using a REGEX.
My problem is to find and replace a 41k lines file that has insert queries

A tipical set of lines inside this file is

```
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` VALUES ('Holtsville', 'NY', '00501', '40.8152', '-73.0455', 'Suffolk');
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` VALUES ('Holtsville', 'NY', '00544', '40.8152', '-73.0455', 'Suffolk');
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` VALUES ('Adjuntas', 'PR', '00601', '18.1788', '-66.7516', 'Adjuntas');
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` VALUES ('Aguada', 'PR', '00602', '18.381389', '-67.188611', 'Aguada');
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` VALUES ('Aguadilla', 'PR', '00603', '18.4554', '-67.1308', 'Aguadilla');
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` VALUES ('Aguadilla', 'PR', '00604', '18.4812', '-67.1467', 'Aguadilla');
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` VALUES ('Aguadilla', 'PR', '00605', '18.429444', '-67.154444', 'Aguadilla');
```

I wanna replace each `INSERT INTO`cities_extended`VALUES ('%1', '%2',`
WITH `SELECT C.id FROM CITY C WHERE C.name = '' and C.state = ''` so my entire file would look like that

```
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` VALUES (SELECT C.id FROM CITY C WHERE C.name = 'Holtsville' and C.state = 'NY', '00501', '40.8152', '-73.0455', 'Suffolk');
```

How to do this with UltraEdit or any other tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Notepad++:

Search: `VALUES\s+\(\s*('.+?'),\s*('.+?')(.+)\)`

Replace: `VALUES \(SELECT C.id FROM CITY C WHERE C.name = $1 and C.state = $2 $3\)`